# Trigonometric base of functions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Is it possible to write function $\pi - x^2$ as a linear combination of base $\{ 1, \cos x, \sin x, \cos 2x, \sin 2x, \cos 3x, \sin 3x, \dotsc\}$?

Comment: No, not as a linear combinaison, because in mathematics, a linear combinaison is defined as a finite linear combinaison. As you probably want an infinite linear combinaison, look at Fourier series

Comment: Is it possible to write this as a fourier series?

Answer (score 4):

No, because all of those function is periodic with period $2\pi$ (not necessarily the "fundamental period") so any linear combination of them is period with period $2\pi$ and $\pi- x^2$ is not.